# Multi-label classification using output quantization

Tags: machine-learning

### Problem statement

It's a fact that in order to train the network for multilabel-dataset, a one-hot-vector output is usually used.

**Example:**

> dog         [1 0 0]
>
> cat         [0 1 0]
>
> rabbit      [0 0 1]

Consequently, we're increasing size of the weight matrix as well as the required training time.

---

Question: Is there an approach that we can use one output and quantize it for different classes?

**Example:**

> 0 <= output < =1
>
> dog [0.0 - 0.33]
>
> cat [0.33 - 0.66]
>
> rabbit [0.66 - 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

Bad idea, don't do that.

## Explanation

1)
You are introducing an ordering in the classes that doesn't exist. Basically, with your example, you are saying that: "`dog` is close to `cat`", "`cat` is close to `rabbit`", but "`dog` is *far* from `rabbit`", which is an extra learning feature your network needs to learn.

For example, if the network outputs `0.35`, then it is class `cat` but it is also close to `dog` and far from `rabbit`.

2)
Another problem, that some results are not possible to be represented.

For example, what if you changed the range to:

> 0 <= output < =1
>
> cat [0.0 - 0.33]
>
> rabbit [0.33 - 0.66]
>
> dog [0.66 - 1]

How will you represent that the same example from before ("it is class `cat` but it is also close to `dog` and far from `rabbit`.")? It become impossible.

With the previous representation you could have:

```
output = [0.5, 0.0, 0.5] # cat, rabbit, dog
```

how would you map that to the new range where `cat = [0.0-0.33]` and `dog = [0.66-1.0]`? Can we pick the middle (`0.5`)? No, because that is class `rabbit`.

## Conclusion

By doing that, you reduce the number of weights in the final layers (good), however, you introduce dependencies which needs to be learned and some results are not representable or interpretable.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Perform one label encoding and then normalise the column.